# I'm trying to import an fxml file into my main class and Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource()); returns null

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import an fxml file into my main class and Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(/View/Main_Form.fxml)); returns null.

It basically is telling me that it can't find the "Main_Form.fxml" file that I am asking it to find.

I have it in a package labeled "View" which is the path I specified.

code is as follows:

```
`package com.example.c482_1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {



        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Main_Form.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}`
```

[file structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTR8T.png)

I have tried checking the path, I made my main project the resource root with no luck as well.

Comment: Your package for the fxml files is `View` (shown in the image) yet you are telling the loader that it is `view`: `getClass().getResource("/view/..")`. Side note: the Java package naming convention says package names should begin with a lower case letter. The package you seem to have inherited from the instructor (com.example.c482_1) follows this convention. I suggest you rename your packages according to the convention.

Comment: I tried this however the error still happens, do you think I am setting the path correctly?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the fxml files are not being copied to the `build/classes/java/main/View` folder. I usually put the fxml files in a parallel package structure in the `src/main/resources` path. It looks like you are using Maven, but with Gradle, fxml files in `src/main/java` weren't copied unless I added an include in the sourceSet configuration. So, I just make a habit of putting them in the resources path.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure but I would try checking to make sure the path is relative

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).